# Insert multiple data into multiple rows into an SQL table in Java

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

I am a bit stuck. I have a linked list with customer and booking data. I have to insert the data from the linked list into 2 SQL tables (Customer and Booking).

The first 9 strings in my linked list are customer details, the 10-18th strings are the booking data. (these were read from a CSV).

My code does not throw any errors, but the 'Customer" table never gets filled in with any data.

I have tried the code below, but have no luck.

```
bookings = new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList(splitString));

try {
sqlConnection.setAutoCommit(false);

String sql = "INSERT INTO Customer (customerid, title, firstname, lastname, email, phone, PLnumber, country, expiry) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";

java.sql.PreparedStatement ps = sqlConnection.prepareStatement(sql);

for (int i = 1; i < 1 ; i++) {
ps.setString(1, bookings.get(i));
ps.setString(2, bookings.get(i + 1));
ps.setString(3, bookings.get(i + 2));
ps.setString(4, bookings.get(i + 3));
ps.setString(5, bookings.get(i + 4));
ps.setString(6, bookings.get(i + 5));
ps.setString(7, bookings.get(i + 6));
ps.setString(8, bookings.get(i + 7));
ps.setString(9, bookings.get(i + 8));
ps.addBatch();

}
ps.executeBatch();
sqlConnection.commit();
```

Comment: `for (int i = 1; i < 1 ; i++) {`  what do you think this part does?

Comment: That was just for testing to insert 9 strings into my 'Customer' table.

Comment: Are you aware the entire block in the for loop does not gets executed?

Comment: You don't need any loop. And accessing a linked list by index is extremely inefficient. Why use a linked list? Why not have two object Customer and Booking, with named, typed fields?

Comment: No, and you just solved my problem :) Rookies mistake, because I am a rookie. Thank you!

Comment: I had to use linked list, this is an assignment.

Comment: @Stephan Hogenboom I have one more problem though. The first field of my 'Customer' table is AUTO_INCREMENT. What do I insert into this one? If I insert nothing, I get this 'java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 1'. Thnak you in advance.

Comment: This is just a guess, but probably an auto increment. (increasing it by 1 for everyone row put in)

Comment: @Attila - Simply omit the AUTO_INCREMENT column from your INSERT statement.

Comment: @Attila does the database handle the auto_increment or do you want your app to do the increment? If the database handles the increment you can remove the custumorid and the corresponding `?` from your query